# Can you fix this regex?

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm terrible with RegEx and found this bit somewhere on the interwebs.  It's for matching Twitter-style @username but it has one small problem - it also accepts a space as a word.

```
NSRegularExpression *atRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<!\\w)@([\\w\\._-]+)?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

Example: "@erik" is matched correctly, but "@ erik" is also matched and should not be.

Comment: *"I'm terrible with RegEx"* Isn't **that** the problem you should really be fixing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression contains

```
@(...)?
```

The `?` at the end means that everything inside the preceding `(...)` is completely optional. So, your regex doesn't have to match anything following a @.

To fix this, you may be able to remove the `( )?`, leaving:

```
"(?<!\\w)@[\\w\\._-]+"
```

However, you should also investigate what that `(?<!\\w)` is doing for you and whether you need it.

Comment: He probably needs it to avoid matching an email address. `(?<!\\w|^)` would probably work better if that regex engine supports variable-length lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

The reason @ erik is matched is most likely becuase your capturing group is:

```
([\\w\\._-]+)
```

That means one or more word characteres, periods, underscores, or dashes. So @ erik is matched sinced "erik" meets this criteria. The lookbehind asertion and the @ symbol are not being included in the match group, but they should be since they are the criteria for a match.

Try combining the zero-width negative lookbehind asertion you have

```
(?!<\\w)
```

which means any non-word character, into your capture group. It will not be included in the match, but will combine to mean "find a string of one or more word characters, periods, underscores, or dashes, following a non-word character and the "@" symbol. As Tim pointed out, this is to avoid email matches.

Try this:

```
"((?<!\\w)@[\\w\\._-]+)"
```

*Please note that I am not an objective-c programmer, so I am not familiar enough with it to know if you need to write \\w instead of \w. In the flavors of regex I am used to, you would only use one escape character. Please consult your documentation if the above does not work.

Answer (score 0):

@\S*

http://regexpal.com/ can really help in a bind

Comment: That won't help, because your regex will also match @ followed by a space.

Comment: That would mean a "@" symbol followed by ZERO or more non-whitespace (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) characters. So anything that contains "@" is a match.